# Revert reason: Ownable: caller is not the owner

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin

I am having the following contract:

```
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

import "./IERC165.sol";
import "./IERC721.sol";
import "./IERC721Enumerable.sol";
import "./ERC165.sol";
import "./Strings.sol";
import "./Address.sol";
import "./IERC721Metadata.sol";
import "./IERC721Receiver.sol";
import "./ERC721.sol";
import "./ERC721Enumerable.sol";
import "./Ownable.sol";

contract rNFT is ERC721Enumerable, Ownable {
    using Strings for uint256;

    string baseURI; //NFT json is saved
    string linkURL;
    string public baseExtension = ".json";
    uint256 public cost; // = 0.0 ether;
    uint256 public maxMintAmount = 1;
    bool public isInVault = false;

    event Logging(string value);

    constructor(
        string memory _name,
        string memory _symbol,
        string memory _initBaseURI
    ) ERC721(_name, _symbol) {
        setBaseURI(_initBaseURI);
    }

    // internal
    function _baseURI() internal view virtual override returns (string memory) {
        return baseURI;
    }

    // public
    function mint(string memory _linkURL) public payable returns (uint) {
        uint256 supply = totalSupply();
        uint256 tokenID = supply + 1;

        if (msg.sender != owner()) {
            require(msg.value >= cost);
        }

        emit Logging(_linkURL);
        setLinkURL(_linkURL);

        _safeMint(msg.sender, tokenID);

        return tokenID;
    }

    function walletOfOwner(address _owner)
        public
        view
        returns (uint256[] memory)
    {
        uint256 ownerTokenCount = balanceOf(_owner);
        uint256[] memory tokenIds = new uint256[](ownerTokenCount);
        for (uint256 i; i < ownerTokenCount; i++) {
            tokenIds[i] = tokenOfOwnerByIndex(_owner, i);
        }
        return tokenIds;
    }

    function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId)
        public
        view
        virtual
        override
        returns (string memory)
    {
        require(
            _exists(tokenId),
            "ERC721Metadata: URI query for nonexistent token"
        );

        string memory currentBaseURI = _baseURI();
        return
            bytes(currentBaseURI).length > 0
                ? string(
                    abi.encodePacked(
                        currentBaseURI,
                        tokenId.toString(),
                        baseExtension
                    )
                )
                : "";
    }

    //only owner
    function setIsInVault() public onlyOwner {
        isInVault = true;
    }

    function setLinkURL(string memory _linkUrl) public onlyOwner {
        linkURL = _linkUrl;
    }

    function setCost(uint256 _newCost) public onlyOwner {
        cost = _newCost;
    }

    function setmaxMintAmount(uint256 _newmaxMintAmount) public onlyOwner {
        maxMintAmount = _newmaxMintAmount;
    }

    function setBaseURI(string memory _newBaseURI) public onlyOwner {
        baseURI = _newBaseURI;
    }

    function setBaseExtension(string memory _newBaseExtension)
        public
        onlyOwner
    {
        baseExtension = _newBaseExtension;
    }

    function withdraw() public payable onlyOwner {

        // Do not remove this otherwise you will not be able to withdraw the funds.
        (bool os, ) = payable(owner()).call{value: address(this).balance}("");
        require(os);
    }
}
```

All above imports are contracts from openzeppelin.

When calling the `mint` function with parameters I get in ganache:

```
[9:49:22 PM] eth_getTransactionCount[9:49:24 PM] eth_blockNumber[9:49:37 PM] eth_sendRawTransaction[9:49:39 PM]   Transaction: 0xcf9c12e58bf28a20a91bce248f1568263f4744bc31f7220f39e3add21a93ce4b[9:49:41 PM]   Gas usage: 28684[9:49:41 PM]   Block Number: 10[9:49:41 PM]   Block Time: Wed May 25 2022 21:49:39 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)[9:49:41 PM]   Runtime Error: revert[9:49:41 PM]   Revert reason: Ownable: caller is not the owner
```

I am having:

```
npm --version = 8.5.5
node --version = v16.15.0
truffle --version = Truffle v5.5.5 - a development framework for Ethereum
Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
```

My `mint()` is public and can be called from everyone.

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Probably because your `mint()` calls `setLinkURL()`

```
emit Logging(_linkURL);
setLinkURL(_linkURL);
```

which is protected by `onlyOwner`:

```
function setLinkURL(string memory _linkUrl) public onlyOwner {
                                                   ^^^^^^^^^
```

If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted. https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Have a great day
Patric